# Is there a limit on padding, margin and transform values?

Tags: css

Is there a limit on the amount of `padding` / `margin` / `translateX` / etc a `div` can have ?

For instance, would something like `margin-left: 999999999px` work reliably across browsers ?

Comment: I'd be careful going over any "obvious" values, like 2^31 or 2^32, type thing.

Comment: You're probably right. But quite frankly, knowing IE8 a bit and having to work with it atm, I'd be careful with anything above 31 :-)

Comment: What Marc said. Just out of curiosity, why on earth would you need something like `margin-left: 999999999px`?

Comment: Well, if you open this gist - https://gist.github.com/conradkleinespel/1131c723eec6a34a0d32 -  in your browser (it's just HTML / JS in a single file), you'll understand: a div's padding is incremented in an interval that is never meant to stop. If you leave your browser open for a period long enough to break the padding limit (if there is any such limit), I have no idea what happens (and btw, I'm open to suggestions on how to implement this in a more reliable way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS3 standard (http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#lengths) does not specify a limit for lengths, it just states that it is a dimension (a number/integer with a unit identifier). And it doesn't specify a limit for integers either.

MDN gives the same description, but on this page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/integer) it states that

> There is no official range of valid  values. Opera supports
>   values up to 2^15-1, IE up to 2^20-1 and other browsers even higher.
>   During the CSS3 Values cycle there were a lot of discussion about
>   setting a minimal limit to support: the latest decision, in April 2012
>   during the LC phase, was [-2^27-1; 2^27-1] # but other values like 2^24-1
>   and 2^30-1 were also proposed # #. The latest Editor's draft doesn't
>   list a limit anymore.

So I guess the limit will depend on the limits set by the browser that you use.